# Metric to count number of 2xx requests to cloud run for past 28 days

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm looking for a way to count the number of successful requests to my cloud run service for the past 28 days. Cloud run exposes the `request_count` metric, but this is sampled every 60 seconds. I would like to aggregate that over the last 28 days.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Why? It does not sound for monitoring, more for statistics and analytics, isn't it?

Comment: It is specifically for monitoring. I want a SLO for the last 28 days. I'm basically looking for a way to compute the good/total requests ratio over the past 28 days. All the docs online result in an "instantaneous" SLO

Comment: Yes, because you should estimate a "budget" every day. If this budget goes bellow your SLO, you need to stop the release and fix the issue to gain budget again (SRE practices). It's not at the end of the month that you have to think about your SLO and your budget. Maybe you have to perform reporting every month to a manager or to a customer. But it's not monitoring, it's reporting, not the same use case, and not the same tools to use!

Comment: The rolling 28 days Vs 1 day is another debate, both make sense from a SRE point of view. What I'm saying is that my SLO is calculated every minute. It's not even calculated over 1 day. See here for more context: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/301232485?pli=1

Comment: Have you tried utilizing [custom metrics](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/custom-metrics-opentelemetry-sidecar) with an OpenTelemetry Sidecar or using [distributed tracing](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/trace)? Both can be used for monitoring Cloud Run.